# Brachos in Zeraim?

Tags: tractate-brachot

Why is Maseches Brachos in Seder Zeraim? It just doesn't seem to fit with the theme of agriculture. I've asked around and the only answer I got was because some Brachos are on seeds, but that doesn't sound right. Please cite sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the *Rambam*'s introduction to the *Mishna*, in my own, loose translation:

> When a doctor wants to keep a patient healthy, he first adjusts his diet. Thus, the wise compiler of the *Mishna* started with *B'rachos*, adjusting our diet, for no one may eat before saying a *b'racha*. Then, so as to deal with a complete topic, he spoke of *b'rachos* in general; and because he would speak of the *b'rachos* said for "*Sh'ma*", and saying "*Sh'ma*" is a *mitzva* every day, he had to first speak of "*Sh'ma*" itself, which is thus how he started the *Mishna*.

Comment: FYI, the same Ramba"m intro also explains more specifically why Brachot began with Kri'at SHema. It is summarized in http://dafnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Brachos_2.pdf.

Comment: See also Rabenu Yona at the begining of Pirke Avot. מאן דבעי למהוי חסידא, (avot, brachot, nezikin)he asks also why not as avot int in nezikin

Comment: @DanF ... that's already in this answer post.